# Float words on an image and be responsive?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a form on my background image, and still have it resize properly (even if I have to do media calls). I have been able to get it to be in the right spot, but not when I resize the window.

I have this html:

```
<html><head>
... links and js
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<main role="main"><div id="home-page-wrap">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img id="full-notebook" class="notebook-img" src="/assets/full-notebook-4408c34201b7213bbdc584452ea7365f.png" alt="Full notebook">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-4" id="menu-wrap">
          <div id="main-page-form-wrap">
            <form id="main-page-form">
              <h2 id="menu-head">
                COMPOSITION
              </h2>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div></main>

</body></html>
```

This is my image (800x1054, but I can resize), and I am trying to get a form to be in the white part of the notebook:

[image: notebook-img]

I can also create the white part as a seperate element if that helps.

<s>added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5hbh9g3/2/</s>  my fiddle was not giving everything.

Added a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/tsDRUp0wym

Comment: Have you tried by setting the image to be the background of the form and position it in center

Comment: I have, but I think I have to adjust the y coordinate some how (its in the black part).

Comment: can you please fiddle it

Comment: I have made some few changes try it http://jsfiddle.net/m5hbh9g3/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also believe that absolute positioning would be your best option here. If you want a fluid layout I would go with percentages in stead of pixels though.

For the best responsive result, I would set that background as an actual image and give it a width of 100% and a height of auto. This way it will always cover the full width of its parent, and maintain aspect ratio.

Then you have to calculate the position of the white square in percents. The following image illustrates how easy that is

[image]

And then it is just a matter of using those percentages to position the form:

```
#main-wrap form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 14.7%;
    left: 27.5%;
    width: 55.6%;
    height: 22.9%;
}
```

And here is the updated fiddle (with a red outline around the form to demonstrate). Resize it and the form should remain in place. Note that you may have to go for an alternative layout on small screens, as the form will become very small and not that user friendly...

http://jsfiddle.net/m5hbh9g3/6/

Comment: apparently, my fiddle wasn't centering the image... I made a bootply (since I'm using bootstrap).

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
#main-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
#main-wrap img, #main-wrap h2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
#main-wrap h2 {
    top: 200px;
    padding-left: 4em;
}
```

Your notebook image is now contained within a `<img>` tag and I am positioning everything absolutely along with a transform, this ensures centering. The `h2` has some padding which should scale if you change your font size.

http://jsfiddle.net/m5hbh9g3/5/